# java program only gives first column of database table "Users" MSSQL

Tags: java, sql-server

I am having an issue where i connect to the database,but cannot retrieve more than the first column even though my query statement is "Select * from Users"
below is my code:

```
import java.sql.*;


public class Connecttodb {
public void dbConnect(String db_connect_string,String db_UserID,String db_UserPass)
{
    try{
        Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(db_connect_string,db_UserID,db_UserPass);
        System.out.println("connected");
        Statement statement= conn.createStatement();
        String querystring = "SELECT * FROM Users";
        ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery(querystring);
        while(rs.next()){
            System.out.println(rs.getString(1));
        }
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Connecttodb connServer= new Connecttodb();
    connServer.dbConnect("jdbc:sqlserver://TGOURDINE-PC\\SQLEXPRESS;databaseName=picture website", "tgourdine", "thomas");
}
```

}

the result is only the first column, UserID:

```
connected
1
2
3
```

The result i want is as follows:

> ```
> connected
> 1 tgourdini thomas NULL NULL
> 2 Geoff     Marley NULL NULL
> 3 tara      Elaine NULL NULL
> ```

thank you,

Comment: Well, you ask for _the first column of each row_ as a string; did you expect anything else?

Comment: Also I would be remiss if I didn't point out that you should probably never  `SELECT * FROM` anything programmatically. It would always be best to select just the columns you need, and add a `WHERE` clause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you only retrieve the first column

```
System.out.println(rs.getString(1));
```

Change your loop to

```
while(rs.next())
    System.out.println(rs.getString(1) + " " + rs.getString(2) + " " + rs.getString(3) + " " + rs.getString(4));
```

Have a look at the documentation of `getString`

> Retrieves the value of the **designated column** in the current row of
>   this ResultSet object as a String in the Java programming language.

Also have a look at the received parameter documentation

> columnIndex - the first column is 1, the second is 2, ...

Answer (score 1):

According to the  [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getString(int)) getString(1) will return only the first column.